# Is it Possible to Deploy WordPress Blog on MERN Google App Engine?

Tags: node.js, wordpress, google-app-engine

I want to know whether or not it's possible to run both a MERN application and a WordPress blog on the same App Engine for Google's App Engine?

Every tutorial I watch to install WordPress on App engine, indicates that it has to be set up in a PHP environment (understandable), but that would directly contradict the Node environment I've set up for my MERN application.

Does anyone know if it's possible and know of any tutorials?

Answer (score 0):

Run Wordpress on Google Cloud App Engine, it works with MySQL database, this is the [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-wordpress-on-appengine-standard) ; run a MERN application on Google Cloud App Engine, it works with MongoDB database, this is the [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/mongodb-atlas-appengineflex-nodejs-app?hl=en_US&_ga=2.49914214.190710130.1581367723-709885236.1578004034), you have to deploy them on different instances via Google App Engine.

Comment: Ok, and then from there do I just change the wordpress home page to be /blog? Instead of just on the regular domain?

Comment: And do I do that through the DNS or the WordPress installation process? I'm familiar with setting up WordPress, but using the Google App Engine and such is confusing to me.

Comment: Following the tutorial to setup Wordpress via GCloud SDK tools on Google App Engine standard environment, you don't go through the additional installation process , the next step is to setup your domain name and DNS settings, this tutorial[link](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/quickstart) that explains how to do this. There are several ways to install Wordpress on Google Cloud Platform[link](https://cloud.google.com/wordpress/), you can find a suitable one of them if you are still confuse to use the Google App Engine.